# Qual o significado do erro de "indexação igual ou removida" no MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: erro]
[image: indices]

Estou trabalhando com pequenos relacionamentos e percebi que em uma tabela estado em que relacionei o campo `id` a tabela `país[id]` me aparece esta mensagem de erro ou alerta, não tenho certeza. Já em um relacionamento da tabela `cidade` a tabela `estado[id]` não tenho este erro.

Podem me ajudar a saber porque ocorre este erro na relação `estado - país?`

Meu SQL é este:

```
$criar      = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $aonde.$tablee (
        id          INT(6)  UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nome        VARCHAR(75) DEFAULT NULL,
        uf          VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,
        pais        INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL, 
                    PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY fk_Estado_pais (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28";
```

Comment: acho q vc tem q setar o fk_Estado_pais ... tipo em mysql ficaria : foreign key(pais) references fk_Estado_pais(id).

Answer (score 7):

Esse erro indica que tens duas chaves de indexação iguais, onde essencialmente estás a repetir dados na indexação da tabela. O MySQL avisa porque indexação duplicada acaba por afetar a performance das consultas.

#### No teu SQL é visível a duplicação em questão:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY fk_Estado_pais (id)
```

Tens a tua chave primária da tabela no campo `id` e posteriormente tens uma nova chave de indexação no mesmo campo `id` com o nome `fk_Estado_pais`.

#### Já o erro que obténs:

> A indexação PRIMARY e fk_Estado_pais parecem ser iguais ou uma delas pode ter sido removida.

Parece-me estar mal traduzido face ao seu original porque a informação dada pelo mesmo não coincide com a informação na tabela de indexação ou com a informação no teu SQL. Mas é uma suposição pois só com o código MySQL associado a esse erro é que consigo saber os detalhes originais do mesmo.

## Solução

Para uma indexação de acordo com a tua descrição, usando apenas `PRIMARY KEY(id)` é mais que suficiente dado ser um valor indexado e único que permite um relacionamento excelente com a outra tabela.